# How to show 12 months at once in AngularFull Calendar module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i'm trying to implement a calendar in angular Full calendar library. Is there a way i can show all 12 months of a year at once. so fare I've only managed to show one month at a time.

if this library doesn't provide this feature is there anything else i can use to accomplish this task.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

its brilliant library, you can do all kind of date/time related tasks